How can I rewrite macro calls while preserving comments in the arguments?
I have an application that rewrites various C language expressions
including
clang::ConditionalOperator
(ternary expressions).  I want to know how to
rewrite expressions that result from the expansion of macros while
preserving any comments that may appear in the macro arguments,
as well as inserting surrounding instrumentation code.
For example, if the original code (over which I have no control)
contains:
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
    MAX(/*C1*/12/*C2*/, /*C3*/34/*C4*/)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              a               b

then I want the written code to be:
    (/*PRB #0*/ (((/*C1*/12/*C2*/) > (/*C3*/34/*C4*/)) ? (/*C1*/12/*C2*/) : (/*C3*/34/*C4*/)))
     ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     instrmntn.           a                  b                  a                   b

That is, we can think of the transformation as:

Expand the macro while preserving comments in the arguments.

Recognize (say) a ternary expression and insert instrumentation.


How can I implement that transformation using the Clang C++ API?
Complete program containing my current attempt
The full source of my current attempted solution is:
    // SYSTEM INCLUDES
    #include <iostream>
    #include <filesystem>
    #include <range/v3/all.hpp>
    #include <clang/AST/ASTContext.h>
    #include <clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h>
    #include <clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h>
    #include <clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h>
    #include <clang/Basic/SourceLocation.h>
    #include <clang/Basic/SourceManager.h>
    #include <clang/Frontend/ASTUnit.h>
    #include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
    #include <clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h>
    #include <clang/Serialization/PCHContainerOperations.h>
    
    // APPLICATION INCLUDES
    // EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS
    // EXTERNAL VARIABLES
    // CONSTANTS
    // DEFINES
    // STRUCTS
    // NAMESPACE USAGE
    using namespace llvm;
    
    // STATIC VARIABLE INITIALIZATIONS
    namespace {
        //! The CProbe tool category.
        cl::OptionCategory gToolCategory("CProbe Tool Category");
  
        unsigned gProbeIndex = 0u;
        auto getProbeInfo(
            const clang::SourceManager& SM,
            const clang::CharSourceRange& SR,
            const clang::FunctionDecl* FD) ->
                std::tuple<clang::SourceLocation, unsigned, std::string, std::string> {
            // Handle location when macro.
            const auto beginLoc = SM.getExpansionLoc(SR.getBegin());
            const auto lineNumber = SM.getSpellingLineNumber(beginLoc);
            const auto fileName = SM.getFilename(beginLoc).str();
            const auto functionName = FD->getName().str();
            return {beginLoc, lineNumber, fileName, functionName};
        }
    }
    
    namespace util {
        namespace rv = ranges::views;
        inline constexpr auto trim_front = rv::drop_while(::isspace);
        inline constexpr auto trim_back = rv::reverse | trim_front | rv::reverse;
        inline constexpr auto trim = trim_front | trim_back;
    
        inline std::string trim_str(const std::string& s) {
            return s | trim | ranges::to<std::string>;
        }
    
        inline std::vector<std::string> split (std::string& s, const char delim) {
            return ranges::actions::split(s, delim);
        }
    }
    
    namespace tooling {
        // Recursive CProbeVisitor visitor class.
        class CProbeVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<CProbeVisitor> {
        public:
            explicit CProbeVisitor(
                clang::ASTContext& rContext,
                clang::Rewriter& rRewriter)
                : mContext{rContext}
                , mRewriter{rRewriter}
            {}
    
            static bool shouldTraversePostOrder() {
                // Must return true to traverse the AST in post-order.
                return true;
            }
    
            bool TraverseFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *FD) {
                const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                if (!SM.isInMainFile(SM.getExpansionLoc(FD->getLocation()))) {
                    // Skip this FunctionDecl and continue traversal.
                    return true;
                }
    
                // Breadcrumb to access function name in other VisitStmt callbacks.
                mCurrentFunction = FD;
    
                const bool shouldContinue = RecursiveASTVisitor::TraverseFunctionDecl(FD);
    
                if (!shouldContinue) {
                    // Stop traversal.
                    return false;
                }
    
                // This is called when exiting the function.
                // You can put your function exit logic here.
                return true;  // Continue traversal.
            }
    
            //! Visitor callback for 'clang::ConditionalOperator' (ternary expression).
            bool VisitConditionalOperator(const clang::ConditionalOperator *CO) const {
                const auto& [SR, condString, rightPad] = getConditionSourceFromStmt(CO);
                if (!condString.empty()) {
                    const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                    const auto& LO = mContext.getLangOpts();
                    const auto& [startLoc, lineNumber,
                        sourcePath, functionName] =
                        getProbeInfo(SM, SR, mCurrentFunction);
                    // Get the text of the sub-expressions, taking into account
                    // rewrites already performed on any of *their* sub-expressions.
                    const auto lhsStartLoc = clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(
                        CO->getQuestionLoc(), 0, SM, LO);
                    const auto lhsEndLoc = CO->getColonLoc();
                    const auto lhsRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                        { lhsStartLoc, lhsEndLoc }, false);
                    const auto lhs = util::trim_str(mRewriter.getRewrittenText(lhsRange));
    
                    const auto rhsStartLoc = clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(
                        SM.getExpansionLoc(CO->getColonLoc()), 0, SM, LO);
                    const auto rhsEndLoc = findNextTokenLocation(
                        SM.getExpansionLoc(CO->getEndLoc()), clang::tok::semi);
                    const auto rhsRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                        { rhsStartLoc, rhsEndLoc }, false);
                    const auto rhs = util::trim_str(mRewriter.getRewrittenText(rhsRange));
                    std::cout << std::format(
                        "conditionalOperator:"
                        "\n  lhsStartLoc: {}"
                        "\n  lhsEndLoc: {}"
                        "\n  rhsStartLoc: {}"
                        "\n  rhsEndLoc: {}\n"
                        , locStr(lhsStartLoc)
                        , locStr(lhsEndLoc)
                        , locStr(rhsStartLoc)
                        , locStr(rhsEndLoc));
    
                    // Instrument the code as follows:
                    const auto probeText = std::format(
                        "/*PRB #{}*/{} ? {} : {}"
                        , gProbeIndex++
                        , condString
                        , lhs
                        , rhs);
                    // Replace the entire ConditionalOperator (ternary) expression.
                    mRewriter.ReplaceText(
                        {startLoc, rhsEndLoc.getLocWithOffset(-1)},
                        probeText);
                }
                // Returning true continues the traversal.
                return true;
            }
    
            //! Visitor callback for 'clang::IfStmt'.
            bool VisitIfStmt(const clang::IfStmt *IS) const {
                if (const auto& [SR, condString, rightPad] =
                        getConditionSourceFromStmt(IS); !condString.empty()) {
                    const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                    const auto& [startLoc, lineNumber,
                        sourcePath, functionName] =
                            getProbeInfo(SM, SR, mCurrentFunction);
                    // Replace the condition string.
                    const auto probeText = std::format(
                        "/*PRB #{}*/{}"
                        , gProbeIndex++
                        , condString);
                    mRewriter.ReplaceText(SR, probeText);
                }
                // Returning true continues the traversal.
                return true;
            }
    
            //! Visitor callback for 'clang::WhileStmt'.
            bool VisitWhileStmt(const clang::WhileStmt *WS) const {
                if (WS->getCond()) {
                    if (const auto& [SR, condString, rightPad] =
                        getConditionSourceFromStmt(WS); !condString.empty()) {
                        const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                        const auto& [startLoc, lineNumber,
                            sourcePath, functionName] =
                                getProbeInfo(SM, SR, mCurrentFunction);
                        // Replace the condition string.
                        const auto probeText = std::format(
                            "/*PRB #{}*/{}"
                            , gProbeIndex++
                            , condString);
                        mRewriter.ReplaceText(SR, probeText);
                    }
                }
                // Returning true continues the traversal.
                return true;
            }
    
            //! Visitor pattern callback for 'clang::DoStmt'.
            bool VisitDoStmt(const clang::DoStmt *DS) const {
                if (DS->getCond()) {
                    if (const auto& [SR, condString, rightPad] =
                        getConditionSourceFromStmt(DS); !condString.empty()) {
                        const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                        const auto& [startLoc, lineNumber,
                            sourcePath, functionName] =
                                getProbeInfo(SM, SR, mCurrentFunction);
                        // Replace the condition string.
                        const auto probeText = std::format(
                            "/*PRB #{}*/{}"
                            , gProbeIndex++
                            , condString);
                        mRewriter.ReplaceText(SR, probeText);
                    }
                }
                // Returning true continues the traversal.
                return true;
            }
    
            //! Visitor callback for 'clang::ForStmt'.
            bool VisitForStmt(const clang::ForStmt *FS) const {
                if (FS->getCond()) {
                    if (const auto& [SR, condString, rightPad] =
                        getConditionSourceFromStmt(FS); !condString.empty()) {
                        const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                        const auto& [startLoc, lineNumber,
                            sourcePath, functionName] =
                                getProbeInfo(SM, SR, mCurrentFunction);
                        // Replace the condition string.
                        const auto probeText = std::format(
                            "(/*PRB #{}*/{}){}"
                            , gProbeIndex++
                            , util::trim_str(condString)
                            , rightPad ? " " : "");
                        mRewriter.ReplaceText(SR, probeText);
                    }
                }
                // Returning true continues the traversal.
                return true;
            }
    
        private:
            //! Source Location printer.
            std::string locStr(clang::SourceLocation loc) const {
                return loc.printToString(mContext.getSourceManager());
            }
    
            [[nodiscard]] auto getConditionSourceFromStmt(const clang::Stmt* stmt) const ->
                std::tuple<clang::CharSourceRange, std::string, bool> {
                const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                const auto& [SR, rightPad] = getConditionSourceRange(stmt);
                if (SM.isWrittenInSameFile(SR.getBegin(), SR.getEnd())) {
                    // Get the text *after* taking prior rewrites into account.
                    return { SR, mRewriter.getRewrittenText(SR), rightPad };
                }
                return {};
            }
    
            //! Helper function to search for token starting from location <code>startLoc</code>.
            [[nodiscard]] auto findNextTokenLocation(
                const clang::SourceLocation& startLoc, const auto& token) const ->
                clang::SourceLocation {
                const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                const auto& LO = mContext.getLangOpts();
                // create a lexer to find the end of the statement/eof.
                const auto lexer = std::make_unique<clang::Lexer>(
                    startLoc, LO, SM.getCharacterData(startLoc),
                    SM.getCharacterData(clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(startLoc, 0, SM, LO)),
                    SM.getCharacterData(SM.getLocForEndOfFile(SM.getMainFileID())));
                //lexer->ExtendedTokenMode = 1; // interpret comments as tokens - ignore whitespace.
                clang::Token tok;
                do {
                    lexer->LexFromRawLexer(tok);
                    if (tok.is(token)) {
                        // return the token location.
                        return tok.getLocation();
                    }
                    // std::cout << "Token text: " << clang::Lexer::getSpelling(tok, SM, LO) << "\n";
                } while (!tok.is(clang::tok::eof));
                return {};
            }
    
            auto getConditionSourceRange(const clang::Stmt* stmt) const ->
                std::pair <clang::CharSourceRange, bool> {
                const auto& SM = mContext.getSourceManager();
                const auto& LO = mContext.getLangOpts();
    
                if (const auto IS = dyn_cast<clang::IfStmt>(stmt)) {
                    // Location after the '('.
                    const auto afterLParenLoc = IS->getCond()->getBeginLoc();
                    // Location before the ')'.
                    const auto beforeRParenLoc = IS->getRParenLoc();
                    const auto conditionRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                        { afterLParenLoc, beforeRParenLoc }, false);
                    return { SM.getExpansionRange(conditionRange), false };
                } else if (const auto WS = dyn_cast<clang::WhileStmt>(stmt)) {
                    // Location after the '('.
                    const auto afterLParenLoc = WS->getCond()->getBeginLoc();
                    // Location before the ')'.
                    const auto beforeRParenLoc = WS->getRParenLoc();
                    const auto conditionRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                        { afterLParenLoc, beforeRParenLoc }, false);
                    return { SM.getExpansionRange(conditionRange), false };
                } else if (const auto DS = dyn_cast<clang::DoStmt>(stmt)) {
                    // Location after the '('.
                    const auto afterLParenLoc = DS->getCond()->getBeginLoc();
                    // Location before the ')'.
                    const auto beforeRParenLoc = DS->getRParenLoc();
                    const auto conditionRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                        { afterLParenLoc, beforeRParenLoc }, false);
                    return { SM.getExpansionRange(conditionRange), false };
                } else if (const auto FS = dyn_cast<clang::ForStmt>(stmt)) {
                    // There are 2 ways to determine the start of the condition
                    // (this is the location past the first semicolon).
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // If an init section is present, There appears to be a lexer bug where
                    // 'FS->getInit()->getEndLoc()' points to 'clang::tok::semi' instead of
                    // pointing to the start token of the init section (see below).
                    //
                    // - Initializer with locally declared type loop variable:
                    //   for (int a = 30 /*FOO*/ ; a<50; ++a) {}
                    //                           ^--- FS->Init()->getEndLoc() points here.
                    //                ^--- FS->Init()->getEndLoc() should point here.
                    // - Initializer with externally declared type loop variable:
                    //   for (a = 30 /*FOO*/ ; a<3; ++a) {}
                    //            ^--- FS->Init()->getEndLoc() points here.
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    clang::SourceLocation afterFirstSemiLoc =
                        clang::Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(
                            FS->getLParenLoc(), clang::tok::semi,
                                SM, LO, false);
                    if (FS->getInit()) {
                        clang::Token token;
                        auto locationStr = locStr(FS->getInit()->getEndLoc());
                        clang::Lexer::getRawToken(FS->getInit()->getEndLoc(), token, SM, LO);
                        if (token.is(clang::tok::semi)) {
                            afterFirstSemiLoc = token.getLocation().getLocWithOffset(1);
                        } else if (SM.isMacroBodyExpansion(FS->getInit()->getEndLoc())) {
                            const auto tokenLen = clang::Lexer::MeasureTokenLength(FS->getInit()->getEndLoc(), SM, LO);
                            afterFirstSemiLoc = SM.getExpansionLoc(FS->getInit()->getEndLoc()).getLocWithOffset(
                                static_cast<clang::SourceLocation::IntTy>(tokenLen));
                        } else {
                            if (const auto tok = clang::Lexer::findNextToken(token.getLocation(), SM, LO); tok) {
                                const auto tokenLen = clang::Lexer::MeasureTokenLength(tok->getLocation(), SM, LO);
                                afterFirstSemiLoc = tok->getLocation().getLocWithOffset(
                                    static_cast<clang::SourceLocation::IntTy>(tokenLen));
                            }
                        }
                        locationStr = locStr(afterFirstSemiLoc);
                    }
    
                    // Get the last token of the condition,
                    // clang::ForStmt have mandatory condition.
                    if (const auto cond = FS->getCond(); cond) {
                        const auto condLastTokenLoc = cond->getEndLoc();
                        // Get the next token, which should be the second semi.
                        if (const auto secondSemiToken =
                            clang::Lexer::findNextToken(condLastTokenLoc, SM, LO); secondSemiToken) {
                            const auto beforeSecondSemiLoc = secondSemiToken->getLocation();
                            std::cout << std::format(
                                "forStmt:"
                                "\n  AfterFirstSemi: {}"
                                "\n  BeforeSecondSemi: {}\n"
                                , locStr(afterFirstSemiLoc)
                                , locStr(beforeSecondSemiLoc));
                            const auto conditionRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                                { afterFirstSemiLoc, beforeSecondSemiLoc }, false);
                            // macro flags used to add extra spaces around the condition.
                            return { SM.getExpansionRange(conditionRange),
                                secondSemiToken->isNot(clang::tok::semi) };
                        }
                    }
                    // invalid return here.
                    return {};
                } else if (auto CO = dyn_cast<clang::ConditionalOperator>(stmt)) {
                    const auto condRange = SM.getExpansionRange(CO->getCond()->getSourceRange());
                    if (CO->getBeginLoc().isMacroID()) {
                        // HELP ME HERE
                        // I do not know how to handle the expanded macro text here and also
                        // in the other dyn_cast<stmt*> calls for these if {} else if {} blocks.
                        std::string stmtStr;
                        llvm::raw_string_ostream stream(stmtStr);
                        CO->printPretty(stream, nullptr, clang::PrintingPolicy(LO));
                        std::cout << stmtStr << "\n";
                        stream.flush();
                    }
                    return { {{condRange.getBegin(), condRange.getEnd()}, true}, false };
                } else if (auto SS = dyn_cast<clang::SwitchStmt>(stmt)) {
                    const auto afterLParen = SS->getLParenLoc().getLocWithOffset(1);
                    const auto beforeRParen= SS->getRParenLoc();
                    std::cout << std::format(
                        "switchStmt:"
                        "\n  AfterLParen: {}"
                        "\n  BeforeRParen: {}\n"
                        , locStr(afterLParen)
                        , locStr(beforeRParen));
                    const auto conditionRange = clang::CharSourceRange(
                        { afterLParen, beforeRParen }, false);
                    return { SM.getExpansionRange(conditionRange), false };
                } else {
                    assert(!"unhandled stmt kind");
                }
                // Not reached.
                return {};
            }
    
            clang::ASTContext& mContext;
            clang::Rewriter& mRewriter;
            const clang::FunctionDecl *mCurrentFunction = nullptr;
        };
    }
    
    /**
     * This is all boilerplate for a program using the Clang C++ API
     * ("libTooling") but not using the "tooling" part specifically.
     * Copy the arguments into a vector of char pointers since that is
     *
     * @param argc
     * @param argv
     *
     * @return
     */
    int main(int argc, char const **argv)
    {
        // Copy the arguments into a vector of char pointers since that is
        // what 'createInvocationFromCommandLine' wants.
        std::vector<char const *> commandLine;
        {
            commandLine.push_back("C:/tools/llvm/bin/clang");
    
            for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
                commandLine.push_back(argv[i]);
            }
        }
    
        // Parse the command line options.
        const std::shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation> compilerInvocation(
            clang::createInvocation(llvm::ArrayRef(commandLine)));
        if (!compilerInvocation) {
            // Command line parsing errors have already been printed.
            return 2;
        }
    
        // Boilerplate setup for 'LoadFromCompilerInvocationAction'.
        const auto pchContainerOps = std::make_shared<clang::PCHContainerOperations>();
        const clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticsEngine> diagnosticsEngine(
            clang::CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(
                new clang::DiagnosticOptions));
    
        // Run the Clang parser to produce an AST.
        const std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTUnit> ast(
            clang::ASTUnit::LoadFromCompilerInvocationAction(
                compilerInvocation,
                pchContainerOps,
                diagnosticsEngine));
    
        if (ast == nullptr || diagnosticsEngine->getNumErrors() > 0) {
            // Error messages have already been printed.
            return 2;
        }
    
        clang::ASTContext& astContext = ast->getASTContext();
        const auto& SM = astContext.getSourceManager();
        clang::Rewriter rewriter(astContext.getSourceManager(), astContext.getLangOpts());
    
    
        tooling::CProbeVisitor visitor(astContext, rewriter);
        visitor.TraverseDecl(astContext.getTranslationUnitDecl());
    
        clang::FileID MainFileID = SM.getMainFileID();
        const auto MainFileRange = clang::SourceRange(
            SM.getLocForStartOfFile(MainFileID),
            SM.getLocForEndOfFile(MainFileID));
    
        std::string FinalSourceCode = rewriter.getRewrittenText(MainFileRange);
    
        // Print the final source code to the console
        std::cout << FinalSourceCode << std::endl;
    
        return 0;
    }

Behavior on test case
When given the input:
#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
void f()
{
    (((/*C1*/12/*C2*/) > (/*C3*/34/*C4*/)) ? (/*C1*/12/*C2*/) : (/*C3*/34/*C4*/));

    MAX(/*C1*/12/*C2*/, /*C3*/34/*C4*/);
}

The above program produces as output:
#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
void f()
{
    (/*PRB #0*/((/*C1*/12/*C2*/) > (/*C3*/34/*C4*/)) ? (/*C1*/12/*C2*/) : (/*C3*/34/*C4*/));

    /*PRB #1*/MAX(/*C1*/12/*C2*/, /*C3*/34/*C4*/) ?  : (/*C1*/12/*C2*/, /*C3*/34/*C4*/);
}

The first rewritten line is correct since it does not use macros.  The
second is garbled, with the macro name MAX still appearing, and other
elements misplaced.

#define MAX(a, b) (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))  is bad practice in C++ for various reasons. MACROS should be a last resort and C++ has std::max and std::min.  And these are just function calls as they should be and they are thus composable (unlike macros).
So first step would be to refactor your code to NOT use macros at all. If you depend on the "C" macro being called (because it is in a 3rd party library), then wrap it in a function or (variadic) function template

@PepijnKramer It is actully legacy C that I am trying to instrument (as clearly stated in the question) - the macro shown is an example of something I found in that legacy C.  To that end, I am working on putting together a fully working example to reproduce my issues.  Did you downvote the question?  Stay tuned for an updated question...

@ScottMcPeak I updated the question per your suggestion - it took longer than expected.  Also as a side note (npt really related to this question), I think you may be interested in the very strange behaviour I handling ForStmts (when the ForStmt's init variable is declared and defined within the forStmt). Not sure if this is a bug in clang but the endLoc points to the semi and not the last token in these cases - I worked around it as you can see - thought you might be interested),

@ScottMcPeak ty for the fantastic question rewrite! I spent some time trimming to reach 30k lines & had to remove many interesting test cases.  You essentially captured what I was looking for (I may tweak your rewrite to add the ability to handle MIN(MAX(a,b), c) like expansions - side note: regarding clang::forStmt init potential bug, I am using clang version 18.1.7 - didn't try other releases.  Again thanks for your help as always.

@johnco3 It's your question so by all means edit as desired.  But just to explain my choice to omit that: I wanted to keep the question as simple and understandable as possible to increase the chance of getting an answer, I'm concerned that even the first case may be too difficult (I don't know how to do it), and I would think that a solution to that would most likely either already work for the composed case or that handling composition would be a straightforward extension.  But again, up to you.

@ScottMcPeak - you have definitely mastered the art of posing a question with the possibiity of receiving an answer - something I have yet to master.  Gosh, if you're stumped, mere mortals have no hope. I wonder if I removed the requirement to preserve comments for expanded macros, perhaps that might be solvable.  Preserving comments especially for expanded macros complicates matters as that is handled by the lexer and non tokenized source ranges (in order to get the trailing comments up to just before semicolon tokens for ex.).

@johnco3 Yes, giving up on preserving comments would make the problem much easier since then one can just synthesize text from the AST.  If you do so, I think you should leave this question as-is (since someone might know how to preserve the comments).  If necessary, ask a new question with the relaxed requirements; and try to focus the question on one specific, important aspect so the the Q+A will be useful to as many other people as possible.

@ScottMcPeak I'll do just that, thanks for the great advice.
